# Notify site users based on user account field (e.g. apt number)

Tags: users, actions

I run a site for my condo, the HOA wants to setup a way to notify residents when they get a package, that needs to get picked up from the office.

In the users account settings their are both unit number and email fields.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: EntityFieldQuery might be useful (I'm using a phone right now so can't put a link to it).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Rules module

[Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules)